# Angular How to filter array data by searching in input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to filter an array object in input text - angular
I'm trying to make an search bar to filter where the user can search the location/description which I name it "sensor".

#### roomlist.component.ts

```
  validateForm: FormGroup;
  rowData: templogRecord[] = [];
  option: any = [];

  onLoad() {
    this.rowData = record.default.records;

    this.option = [];

    this.rowData.forEach(room => {
      this.option.push({
        tooltip: {
          formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c}°"
        },
        toolbox: {
          show: true,
          feature: {
            mark: { show: false },
            restore: { show: false },
            saveAsImage: { show: false }
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: room.sensor,
            type: 'gauge',
            center: ['40%', '70%'],
            splitNumber: 10,
            radius: '70%',
            axisLine: {
              lineStyle: {
                color: [[0.2, '#48b'], [0.8, '#228b22'], [1, '#ff0000']],
                width: 8
              }
            },
            axisTick: {
              splitNumber: 10,
              length: 12,
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'auto'
              }
            },
            axisLabel: {
              textStyle: {
                color: 'auto'
              }
            },
            splitLine: {
              show: true,
              length: 30,
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'auto'
              }
            },
            pointer: {
              width: 5
            },
            title: {
              show: true,
              offsetCenter: [0, '65%'],
              textStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bolder'
              }
            },
            detail: {
              formatter: '{value}°',
              textStyle: {
                color: 'auto',
                fontWeight: 'bolder'
              }
            },
            data: [{ value: this.tempGenerator(), name: "Temperature" }]
          },
          {
            name: '转速',
            type: 'gauge',
            center: ['70%', '25%'],
            splitNumber: 10,
            radius: '40%',
            axisLine: {
              lineStyle: {
                width: 8
              }
            },
            axisTick: {
              length: 12,
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'auto'
              }
            },
            splitLine: {
              length: 20,
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'auto'
              }
            },
            pointer: {
              width: 5
            },
            title: {
              show: true,
              offsetCenter: [0, '80%'],
              textStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bolder',
              }
            },
            detail: {
              formatter: '{value}%',
              offsetCenter: [0, '55%'],
              textStyle: {
                color: 'auto',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: 'bolder'
              }
            },
            data: [{ value: 1.5, name: "Humidity" }]
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  }

  tempGenerator() {

    var time = 12;

    var num = Math.random() * 100;

    var tempBase = Math.round(num);

    var fluc = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 1, 1,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

    return tempBase * fluc[time];
  }

  searchData(searchValue: any) {
    if (searchValue.length >= 3) {
      this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((data: templogRecord) => {
        console.log(data['sensor']);
      });
    } else if (searchValue.length < 1) {
      console.log('empty')
    }
 }
}
```

#### roomlist.json

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Nine Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Ten Line2",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:22:01",
            "sensor": "Eight Line1",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        }
    ]
}
```

**room-list.component.html**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="date-filter">
      <nz-input-group [nzSuffix]="suffixIconSearch">
        <input type="text" 
          nz-input placeholder="Search" 
          [(ngModel)]="filterSearch" 
          (ngModelChange)="searchData($event)"
          />
      </nz-input-group>
      <ng-template #suffixIconSearch>
        <i nz-icon nzType="search"></i>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
    <ul class="cards">
      <li class="cards__item" *ngFor="let data of option">
        <div class="card">
          <div echarts [options]="data" [autoResize]="true"></div>
          <div class="card__content">
            <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

In the `searchData` function, I'm trying to make it filtering while typing based in location/description which I named it "sensor".

Comment: What exactly is your question. How to connect input field with searchData function?

Comment: @J.S. search filtering with list items

Comment: @J.S i updated my code sir

Answer (score 6):

Each time you make a search, you're filtering the elements in your array and giving the output to your original array. Consequently, you loose your data.
Why don't you create 2 variables:

1. The original array which doesn't change ( containing your data ) which should be in a provider but in our example we'll declare it in your component.
2. The filtered array which you're going to display

```
  searchData(searchValue: any) {
      this.filteredData = this.rowData.filter((item: templogRecord) => {
        return item.sensor.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      });
 }
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.filteredData`?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this solution (Based on materials autocomplete: https://stackblitz.com/angular/lndebkoyare?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)

In your component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Filter autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class FilterExample implements OnInit {

  // your control for input
  searchControl = new FormControl();

  // your whole set of options
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

  // your current result based on filters input
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

Your template would look like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="date-filter">
  <nz-input-group [nzSuffix]="suffixIconSearch">
    <input type="text" 
      nz-input placeholder="Search" 
      [formControl]="searchControl"
      />
  </nz-input-group>
  <ng-template #suffixIconSearch>
    <i nz-icon nzType="search"></i>
  </ng-template>
</div>
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="cards__item" *ngFor="let data of filteredOptions | async">
    <div class="card">
      <div echarts [options]="data" [autoResize]="true"></div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Every time value on input changes the observable `valueChanges` on `searchControl` emits the current value of this input field. This part `map(value => this._filter(value))` returns a filtered subset of your options array. Which can be displayd using the async pipe: `<li class="cards__item" *ngFor="let data of filteredOptions | async">...</li>`

Comment: How to apply the array object ? like `rowData: any = [{
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Heat 1",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Dash Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        }]`

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility), because these are not supported by the Internet Explorer.**

How about using javascript's `filter` function? See an example below.

The following example assumes that you are targeting the `sensor` element in the object.

[Click here for a DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ttxn12)

```
 const test = {
    "records": [
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Nine Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Ten Line2",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:22:01",
            "sensor": "Eight Line1",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        }
    ]
};

let found = [];
const searchTerm = 'Eight Line1';
found = test.records.filter(function(element) {
  return element.sensor.toLowerCase() == searchTerm.toLowerCase();
});

console.log('found ' , found[0]);
```

**Update**

To perform a partial search (searching for a part of the string), you can safely use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Browser_compatibility). See an example below,

```
console.log("Eight Line1".indexOf("Ei") !== -1);
```

Hope this helps,

Thanks.

Comment: How to apply when the user just put "heat 1" also "HEAT 1"

Comment: @ABC I'd just add `toLowerCase()` so it will always consider the same case, regardless of the user input case. See the updated answer above.

Comment: After that sir, how do I filter the list items? it should be display the Heat 1, after I type it. cause I tried it before `return this.option = return;` but it doesn't work

Comment: @ABC I have added a demo link. See the code above. Don't forget to open the console.

Comment: @AnjanaSilva - I know this is old but found your answer via search. Your example is fine but what if I wanted to find the results based off a few letters? Right now in your example I have to put 'Eight Line1' but what if I only wanted to put 'Ei'? I am not finding an example anywhere for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DeepToot : Please check my updated answer. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @AnjanaSilva for the update. Really appreciate the help and will try it out this evening.

Comment: @DeepToot No worries :)